# "provided that there was no case" or "provided that there were no case"

Tags: grammar

My doubt is which of the two is grammatically correct. I'm not sure whether 'were' should be used because it is a subjunctive phrase, or if 'were' should only be used if 'cases' was plural. Thank you!

Hi, thanks for your answers. For example: "The value x would be established to be the retail value of the lowest-valued case of a piece of clothing, provided that there was no clear case of a non-piece of clothing that had an equal or greater value".

So, the question is, is it "was" or "were"?

Thanks again!

Comment: Impossible to answer without more context.

Comment: Would you please expand your question, giving some examples and context?

Comment: Example given in the post. Anyway, my question is for any context, in this subjunctive construction, if the thing that has to be provided is singular, should I use "were" or "was". Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have a question, not a doubt. Don't use doubt that way in English: it sounds wrong. Doubt is something to take up with a psychologist or a theologian. You have a question.

Comment: @tchrist Of course I have a doubt. From Merriam-Webster's: uncertainty of belief or opinion that often interferes with decision-making.

Answer (score 1):

I think [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/was-vs-were/) explains it well.

According to this site, from my understanding, using *were* would be the right choice, given that the part "provided that there was no clear case of a non-piece of clothing that had an equal or greater value" is meant as in a theoretical, hypothetical form, something that is in the moment of writing not a reality yet.

If this part though, is a certainty, a fact, than it should be *was* as it  refers to something that is already real.

From the site:

> Use *were* if the state of being you are describing is in no way the current reality. This is true whenever a hypothetical situation is expressed.

Comment: Dear Lawrence: Thanks for your answer. But there is a mistake in Grammarly: the fact that x is hypothetical does not entail that x is not already real. For example, Copernicus had the hypothesis that the Earth revolved around the Sun, and it was in fact the current reality. So my question now becomes: is it "was" or "were" when you just do not know whether it is already real? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

Answer found in Grammarly: it says that it is "were" when the situation is doubtful, so in my case the correct word is "were".

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/343207)

Comment: I have to wait 48 hours to accept my own answer. So I should not thank people here? I won't, but this is the first time I've ever heard that in my life! Just removed the thank-you part. Also: you recommended the deletion of the most useful answer? It escapes me why...